# Правильная архитектура для проверки столкновений

Tags: c++, ооп

Доброго времени суток.

**Суть проблемы**: Имеется класс *Game*, обладающий полем *current_objects:*

```cpp
class Game{
...
private:
    // То, что здесь используется vector на суть задачи не влияет.
    vector<GameObject*>* current_objects;
}
```

Имеется сам класс GameObject, хранящий *object_rect*:

```cpp
class GameObject{
...
private:
    SDL_Rect* object_rect;
}
```

Пытаемся написать функцию, проверяющую столкновения одного объекта с другим. Логично (на мой взгляд) расположить эту функцию внутри класса GameObject, чтобы получилось что-то вроде:

```
// GameObject.h
int check_collision_with_all_objects(); // Возвращает не 0 в случае пересечения с каким-нибудь объектом.

int GameObject::check_collision_with_all_objects(){
    for(auto index = 0; index < CURRENT_OBJECTS->size(); index++){
        auto check_object = CURRENT_OBJECTS.at(index);
        ... // И так далее.
    }
}
```

И всё бы ничего, если не одно бы **но**.

Для проверки столкновений нам **необходимо иметь доступ к *current_objects*** объекта типа *Game*.

---

Казалось бы, ничего серьёзного, стоит просто добавить в *GameObject* поле на подобие "*parent_Game*", и ссылаться на него в проверке. (К слову, это то решение, до которого я дошёл.) Однако такой подход имеет один существенный **минус**.

В моей программе вектор *current_objects* загружается извне, из объекта, который знать не знает об *Game*. То есть, на этапе конструирования *GameObject*-ов я не могу им передавать текущий *Game*. Конечно, это можно обойти, если **при каждой загрузке этого вектора в *Game* проходиться по всем его объектам и менять поле "*parent_Game*"**, но это мне кажется достаточно неэффективным.

---

Если у вас возникнут идеи (*дружественные функции?*) или готовые решения, основанные на опыте, я буду премного благодарен.

Comment: А почему не передавать бы массив объектов в `check_collision_with_all_objects`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Логично (на мой взгляд) расположить эту функцию внутри класса
>   GameObject

Нет, обьект является участником игры, зачем ему знать как и где вы его используете и каким образом строите логику или о существовании других обьектов вообше? Это игра должна строить свою абстракцию_нужно ли в игре определить столкновение или выполнить еще что то. Другое дело, если в `GameObject`  хранить булевский обьект, который в методах `Game` примет обратное значение при столкновении. Не нужно возлогать объязанности одного на другого... Просто сделайте метод `check_collision_with_all_objects()` закрытым методом  `Game`